# Is this linq query efficient?

Tags: linq

Is this linq query efficient?

```
    var qry = ((from member in this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers.Where(m => m.UserId == userId && m.Birthdate == null)
              select member.TreeMemberId).Except(from item in this.ObjectContext.FamilyEvents select item.TreeMemberId));


    var mainQry = from mainMember in this.ObjectContext.TreeMembers
                  where qry.Contains(mainMember.TreeMemberId)
                  select mainMember;
```

Will this be translated into multiple sql calls or just one? Can it be optimised? Basically I have 2 tables, I want to select those records from table1 where datetime is null and that record should not exist in table2.

Comment: Why don't you execute it and see?

Comment: I hate it when people treat StackOverflow as their personal human-powered compiler.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes :- +1. After reading your comment, I would say partially you are right. Thanks for bringing this in notice to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find out if the query will make multiple calls is to set the `.Log` property of the data context.  I typically set it to write to a `DebugOutputWriter`.  A good example for this kind of class can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/carhelpdesk/source/browse/trunk/CarHelpDesk/CarHelpDesk.Web.Models/Utils/DebugTextWriter.cs?spec=svn157&r=93).

For a general way of thinking about it however, if you use a property of your class that does not directly map to a database field in a where clause or a join clause, it will typically make multiple calls.  From what you have provided, it looks like this is **not** the case for your scenario, but I can't absolutely certain and suggest using the method listed above.

Comment: - Wow! Good answer and nice tip about custom property that doesn't map to the database. And yes you are write this is not the case in my scenario.